# PlantUML: With preprocessor, how to check if key is present?

Tags: plantuml

With a dictionary variable, I would like to check the presence of a key

```
!$domain_color?={
    "technical": "#gray"
}

frame input $INPUT_COLOR {
!if "technical" in $domain_color
ABC -> bad
!else
def -> ok
!endif
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's enough to check the value (`!if $domain_color.technical`):

```
@startuml
!$domain_color?={ "technical": "#gray" }
'!$domain_color?={ "fred": "#gray" }

frame input $INPUT_COLOR {
!if $domain_color.technical
ABC -> bad
!else
def -> ok
!endif
@enduml
```

[image]

If you uncomment the line defining `fred` and comment the line defining `technical` you can see that your diagram changes.